# calculating the RMS noise of an accelerometer

Tags: noisefloor

I would like to measure the noise density (microg/sqrt(Hz)) of an accelerometer and then compare the measured one with the typical value in the datasheet.

I know the sensitivity and the sampling frequency; The general formula is also known:               N_RMS=PSD×√BW

The BW will be equal to the half of the sampling frequency. 
referring to the following page:
http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4075.pdf

I should calculate the standard deviation and multiply STD by the inverse of sensitivity. But my question is how to calculate the standard deviation in the LSB (count) format?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You've missed a point. You do not, in fact, know the bandwidth. You've confused the Nyquist Limit with a bunch of other things.

The "sampling rate is twice the bandwidth" concept is actually turning things inside out. The Nyquist sampling theorem says that, for a given signal bandwidth, you must sample at a rate at least twice that in order to accurately reconstruct the signal from the digitized data.

So, given a fixed sampling rate, you must put an analog filter before the data with a bandwidth about half the sampling rate. For accurate results, the filter should be better than a simple RC filter. The more poles, the better (and the harder to make).

Once you've done that, you can take data and do your calculations.

And as for calculating the standard deviation, have you even tried to look it up on Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Comment: Thank you very much , probably i didn't have to read the mentioned reference, because it just made confusions. I acquired some raw data in LSB format, then i calculated the relevant standard deviation , and multiplied it by the inverse of sensitivity; The Bandwidth, I considered as 1.57*Fs/2. However still what i get is less than the mentioned value in the datasheet.

Comment: How much less? Keep in mind that the data sheet value is the maximum. The manufacturer guarantees that the real figure will be equal to or less than that number.

Comment: If it's a digitally-interfaced accelerometer, there is no place to analog filter.